# R interpreter failure?

Tags: r

I don't really even know how to describe what is happening, other than that R knows the value of a variable, but then is applying it incorrectly inside a function.  This is copied directly from my terminal:

```
> n2
[1] 4

> rnorm(n2)
[1]  0.379217 -1.519947  1.602527

> rnorm(4)
[1] -0.93154715 -0.82908620  0.55084001  0.09018763
```

R knows `n2 = 4`, and it knows how to deal with `rnorm(4)`, but somehow `rnorm(n2)` is being read as `rnorm(3)`.

Below is my full code.  I set R to interpret a warning as an error to stop the loop where the problem occurs.  After running this check the value of `n2`, then see what `rnorm(n2)` does.

```
rm(list = ls())
options(warn = 2)
iterations = 1
n = 10
proportions = seq(.3, .7, by = .1)
#stores
y = c()

position = 1

#set var ratio
parameter = 1.25
#loop over proportions
for(p in proportions){
  n1 = p*n
  n2 = n-n1
  for(i in 1:iterations){
    #new ys
    newy1 = sqrt(parameter)*rnorm(n1)
    newy0 = rnorm(n2)
    newy = c(newy1, newy0)
    y[position:(position+n-1)] = newy


    position = position+n
  }
}
```

I am running R 3.2.3 on Windows 7 64 bit.

Sorry it took me a bit to get the question straightened out.  Long time user, first time poster.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO (and R)! When asking questions here, it is strongly encouraged that you provide [minimal questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [reproducible examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). It is also recommended that, especially in cases like this where it is unclear, *what is the expected output*? This is behaving correctly and, to me at least, intuitively.

Comment: So, if `n2==3`, what would you expect `rnorm(n2)` to be if not `rnorm(3)`?

Comment: Sorry, if you look at the code n2 is actually 4.  I accidentally said n2 = 3 when commenting on it.  I fixed that.

Comment: What you show is obviously flawed, so perhaps there is (1) a misunderstanding on your part, (2) a typo in what you have asked, or (3) your R is fundamentally dorked (in a way that I have never seen). Close R, start it again, type in the code above (after the line(s) you are not showing us) and report back.

Comment: I added the full code for clarity.

Comment: I closed and reopened R.  Same problem.  Then I upgraded from 3.2.3 to 3.2.4.  Problem persists.

Comment: You reference an error but do not show us what it is. Please realize that people volunteer their time to help on this site; consider making this easy to support a "drive by answer", meaning we don't have to do a whole lot of typing, executing, etc, in order to extract what you should be providing in the first place.

Comment: I expect rnorm(n2) to return 4 random normal variables when n2 == 4.  It is instead returning 3 of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For clarity to others coming to this page: the code above results in an error:

```
Error in y[position:(position + n - 1)] = newy (from #9) : 
  (converted from warning) number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

This is because the length of the left side of the assignment is not the same as the right:

```
length(position:(position+n-1))
# [1] 10
length(newy)
# [1] 9
```

Tracing back through the code, what is causing `newy` to be shorter?

```
lengths(list(newy1, newy0))
# [1] 6 3
n2
# [1] 4
```

The "3" is the culprit, it should be "4". This is very specifically [R FAQ 7.31](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f):

```
n2 == 4
# [1] FALSE
n2 - 4
# [1] -8.881784e-16
```

Perhaps you should consider using `round`, `floor`, `ceiling`, `as.integer`, or some other function when you assign `n1 = p*n` (since `p` is fractional).

One problem with this phenomenon is that it doesn't always mis-perform.

Comment: Efficiently solved with addition of `round`.  Thank you very much for the help.  Marked as answered.